# Tests writtin with Watin: Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to interface type 'mshtml.DispHTMLDocument'

Tags: c#, nunit, watin

I am trying to fill out form elements on a form which is contained in an IFrame, contained in a parent frame.  It is setup to act as a dialog (hit a button, IFRame pops up).  My code is good (no errors and expected results) up until I attempt to get the IFrame

```
DialogIFrame = MainFrame.Frame(Find.ById("dialogFrame"));
```

When I hit this, it throws the following error

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to interface type 'mshtml.DispHTMLDocument'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{3050F55F-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I am not sure if it matters, but this is a test assembly driven by Nunit.

I am having a very hard time finding anything on this error related to Watin.  Nothing I am finding seems to apply (or is such that I cannot see how it applies).

have any of you run into this and if so how did you (if you did) get past it?

Thanks!!  It is driving me nuts!

Comment: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5.9